# Pandas: Transplant column values from one dataframe based on matching condition of another (and do it in vectorized form)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large dataframes where `df1` has more rows than `df2` due to `df1` operating in a finer time resolution of the logistics in question. I want to match two value columns of `df2` to `df1`, and created a time reference column using the `df.dt.floor()` function so that a `df1.time_ref == df2.time` surjective mapping can be applied.
Imagine something like this:

```
df1:                    df2:
    time    time_ref        time    sale    nbr
0    10.10    01.10        01.10    27344    4
1    17.10    01.10        01.11    31160    5
2    24.10    01.10        01.12    19482    3
3    31.10    01.10
4    07.11    01.11
5    14.11    01.11
6    21.11    01.11
7    28.11    01.11
8    05.12    01.12
```

The goal is to display the fraction of sale/nbr of a month to every week of the month for reference.
It should therefore end up like this:

```
df1:
    time    time_ref    monthlyObjAvg
0    10.10    01.10        6836
1    17.10    01.10        6836
2    24.10    01.10        6836
3    31.10    01.10        6836
4    07.11    01.11        6232
5    14.11    01.11        6232
6    21.11    01.11        6232
7    28.11    01.11        6232
8    05.12    01.12        6494
```

Though I have not thought it through, in SQL this would probably be really easy. Using some near-pseudo SQL, the operation would likely be something of this nature:

```
SELECT df1.*FROM df1, df2
JOIN df2.sale/df2.nbr AS "monthlyObjAvg" WHERE df1.time_ref = df2.time
```

In Pandas I had a much harder time to solve and even research this problem, since all search engine results only lead to either .map() functions, or conditional column selection problems. Note that classical condition selection of the like `df1[df1["time_ref"] == df2["time"]]["sale"]` can not be applied, because comparisons between two dataframes are illegal in Pandas. My instinct was also that Pandas probably had some detection feature that noticed the existence of surjective unambiguous mapping and then rationalized such an expression, but that turned out to be false.

Note that I had already solved this problem using loops before this. Looks like this:

```
advIdx = 0
for n in range(df1.shape[0]):
    for m in range(advIdx, df2.shape[0]):
        if df1['time_ref'][n] == df2['time'][m]:
            df1.loc[n, 'monthlyObjAvg'] = df2.loc[m, 'sale'] / df2.loc[m, 'nbr']
            advIdx = m
            break
```

Employing a forward moving index (since old times are never relevant again), one can even reduce the complexity from n*m to roughly n+m. Yet even with such a dramatic improvement, applying the loop solution to datasets of 10,000-1,000,000+ rows still takes a couple seconds to even minutes to run through, which means it still yet cries for a proper vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0):

While it took a while, I eventually figured out what the Pandas function that managed to simulate the conditional argument. Although it can't do it very straightforwardly, `pandas.merge` pretty much implements the SQL statement above. You have to rename the columns that the "join"/merge will be applied to, which is df2.time here:

```
df2.rename(columns = {'time':'time_ref'}, inplace=True)
```

Then apply the leftside join:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['time_ref'])
```

And finally create the target column and drop the rest:

```
df1['monthlyObjAvg'] = df1['sale']/df2['nbr']
df1.drop(["time_ref", "sale", "nbr"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This properly produces the lightning fast solution I searched for (runs in millisecond range on a 50,000+ sample), but it still seems kind of inelegant. I wanted to leave this here as a buoy for future me-like people wondering about this and using these search terms to find nothing much, since it ***is*** a proper solution after all.

If anyone can donate a more elegant and intuitive way to do this (e.g. directly projecting the fraction into the place that fulfills the conditions, instead of copying all, then calculating, then deleting the copies), then feel welcome to do it.